# Certificate issue when registering for gitlab runner X509: Certificates signed by unknown authority

Tags: git, gitlab, certificate, gitlab-ci

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=miWfgJdC status=couldn't execute POST against https://gitlab.com/api/v4/runners: Post https://gitlab.com/api/v4/runners: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems 
linux-w07w:~ # gitlab-runner --version
Version:      9.5.1
Git revisii a  9-5-stable
GO version:  go1.8.3
Built:        Wed, 04 Oct 2017 16:26:27 +0000
```

I am using opensuse Leap 15.1

Comment: Could you tell us what operating system and version you're using on your runner?  Is there anything else relevant about this system that would be helpful for us to know?

Comment: i have updated the information, i am using openSUSE Leap 15.1
 and gitlab-runner 9.5.1